# Django `request.query_params.get("page")` returns None?

Tags: python, django, redux, next.js, query-string

When I user types in search box and submits, this is how I set the url:

```js
  const submitHandler = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (keyword) {
      Router.push({ pathname: "", query: { keyword: keyword, page: 1 } });
    } else {
      Router.push(Router.router?.asPath as string);
    }
  };
```

this is how it looks on the url:"http://localhost:4500/?keyword=ca&page=1"

I use Next.js for front end and this is how I send the query params.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async (context) => {
    const { store, query } = context;
    console.log("params", query);
    store.dispatch(fetchProductsStart(query));
    store.dispatch(END);
    await (store as SagaStore).sagaTask.toPromise();
    const state = store.getState();
    const productListState = state.productList ? state.productList : null;
    return { props: { productListState } };
  }
);
```

`console.log("params", query)` returns this object:"{ keyword: 'g', page: '1' }". This is what I am sending to backend.
Here is "fetchProductsStart"

```js
export const fetchProductsStart = (
queryParams: {keyword:string,page:string}
): actions.IFetchProductsStart => ({
  type: ProductListActionTypes.PRODUCT_LIST_START,
  payload: queryParams,
});
```

This is how I tried to get the params in the backend:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    q=request.query_params.get("page")
    print("page query param",q)
    query = request.query_params
    print("query_params",query)
```

`print("page query param",q)` returns "None"

`print("query_params",query)` returns "<QueryDict: {'[object Object]': ['']}>"

The issue so far I was sending an object. Instead I stringified it "

```
store.dispatch(fetchProductsStart(JSON.stringify(query)));
```

now in backend

```
query = request.query_params
print("query",query)
```

it prints: `query <QueryDict: {'{"keyword":"m","page":"1"}': ['']}>`

but `request.query_params.get("keyword")` is still not working. It returns None

Comment: Can you share the fetchProductsStart function? Are you sure the contents of “query” is being sent as query params?

Comment: `q=request.query_params.get("page")` looks for page in`<url>/?page=<your query>`   looks like there is no parameter `page` in request url.

Comment: @ItsMilann this is the url on browser: "http://localhost:4500/?keyword=ca&page=1"

Comment: do `request.GET.get("page")`

Comment: @acw it returns this : ('[object Object]', '')

Comment: I see; more of a JS question. Just for more debugging purposes, in your views.py, can you add: `request.build_absolute_uri()`

Comment: @Yilmaz `[object Object]` is the string representation of an object in JavaScript. You are not serialising the payload as query parameters correctly.

Comment: @IainShelvington I was just working on it:  I dispatch this :"    store.dispatch(fetchProductsStart(JSON.stringify(query)));"  but i still could not figure out.  I ll update the question

Comment: @Yilmaz somewhere in your JS the URL/querystring is being constructed and you are passing data to it incorrectly or there is a bug there. Is there something in `store.dispatch` that is triggering the call to Django?

Comment: @IainShelvington In which format do i need to send the query params. I used "JSON.strinigfy(query)" and also did "String(query)" still could not figure out

Answer (score 0):

Try getting request parameters like this `request.GET.get('param_name')`

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the way how I passed the query params to the backend:

Instead of this `store.dispatch(fetchProductsStart(JSON.stringify(query)))`

```
store.dispatch(
  fetchProductsStart(`keyword=${query["keyword"]}&page=${query["page"]}`)
);
```